# Is it possible to configure a .deb package, so it only installs on 32-bit operating systems, and not on 64-bit operating systems?

Tags: java, deb

I have developed a Java 8 application.

I have packaged it for Linux systems, self-containing the Java runtime, so users  don't have to deal with Java installation.

I have made a package with the 32-bit Java runtime, and a second one with the 64-bit Java runtime.

In the 64-bit package, I set `Architecture: amd64` in the control file, so it can't be installed on a 32-bit operating system. That works fine.

And in the 32-bit package I set `Architecture: i386`, but this still allows the application to be installed on `amd64` operating systems.

How can I configure the .deb package with the 32-bit JRE, so it can't be installed on 64-bit operating systems? I want to limit it so it can only be installed on 32-bit operating systems.

I want to limit it because installing the app with the 32-bit self-contained Java 8 JRE doesn't work properly on 64-bit systems (I mean without extra work). There are missing libraries: `libxi6`, `libxrender1`, `libxtst6`, `libudev1`. Even if I install them for the `i386` arch, the app doesn't crash but some aspects of the application don't work perfectly, such as MIDI device detection for example.

It would be great if the 32-bit package couldn't be installed on 64-bit operating systems. How can this be achieved?

Comment: If you’re providing this as a `.deb` package, why not depend on the appropriate Java runtime instead of packaging it yourself? That would avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: This was my first approach, but Java 8 dependency is not installed automatically if needed ppa is not set, and last days java 8 ppa have been declared obsolete, so users have to download the appropiata Java package from Oracle website, and configure it so Java 8 is the default Java version, etc.... I prefer not having to explain this to the users of my app... better install and run

Comment: Oh, you’re using the Oracle JRE... IANAL, but I don’t think the Oracle license allows you to do what you’re doing, and you may be exposing your users to liability.

Comment: Self contained packages with bundled JRE is the prefered way to deploy Java apps on Mac Os, and required to publish in Apple Store. Why not do it in Linux? Javapackager is a tool Oracle provides to make self contanied packages. Do you mean Oracel license doesnt allow that?

Comment: Oh, OK, I thought you were manually repackaging the JRE.

Comment: No no, only bundle the JRE on the .deb so users doesn't have to deal with Java 8 installation and configuration. This also ensures Java 8 (and not other version) is used when running the app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think packaging the Java runtime yourself is the best solution, but if it really is unavoidable, you can create a package which will be uninstallable on a system whose main architecture is `amd64` by adding a

```
Conflicts: dpkg:amd64
```

entry to the control file.

(This is guaranteed to be sufficient because a system’s primary architecture is the architecture of the installed `dpkg` package. Since `dpkg` isn’t co-installable on multiple architectures, this approach also avoids excluding multiarch setups capable of running 64-bit programs but not set up with `amd64` as their primary architecture.)

If you do want to continue with your repackaged JRE, I encourage you to check the license of the JRE you’re using, and fix your package so it doesn’t involve manual steps — at least, you should add the library dependencies your JRE needs.

Comment: I have tried and the package is not installed. But no errors are shown if you try to install the package with the Software Installer tool in Ubuntu. No way a friendly message is shown? Sure my users will install double clicking the .deb file

Comment: It’s not possible for a package itself to display an error message when it’s not installed, I would have expected an installation tool to display something though. I’m not familiar with Software Installer.